# Saving quickblox video chat using new API

Tags: quickblox

Quickblox has deprecated their API and SDK for all current examples of saving the AV session. Is there any guidance out there for how I can save a quickblox chat session in iOS using quickblox version >= 6.2 (>= Quickblox-WebRTC 1.0.6)?

Comment: Could you please double-check your iOS SDK version? The latest one is 2.3.0.4, there is no version "6.2".

Comment: @SabinaBashuk sorry, you're right (wires crossed) 2.3.0.4 is the version I have installed with version 1.0.6 Quickblox-WebRTC